# Where am I supposed to keep the data name id on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

As you all know to send data through Activity I have to use the method

```
putExtra (String name, Bundle value)
```

from the starting Activity, and then take the value from the new Activity using

```
 getIntent().getExtra(String name)
```

Well where should I keep the variabile name? Isn't it supposed to be global? Do I have to store it into the Context? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you provide extra pieces of data for your intent, you send some datatype, and you receive some datatype, no global variables are needed, if the received data will be used in the local scope of the receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String PASSING_KEY = "passingKey";
}

putExtra (Constants.PASSING_KEY, Bundle value);
getIntent().getExtra(Constants.PASSING_KEY);
```

make a separate class to store the constants,which would act like global.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store it anywhere. You *can* pass any `String`.

However, I use global variables, so that I don't forget the extra name.

Comment: ...so if I write
putExtra("1", bundle)
and then
getIntent().getExtra("2")
do I get the same bundle????

Comment: No :) you have to do something like getIntent().getStringExtra("1")

Comment: Note that there are several extra accessors in intent: getBundleExtra, getStringExtra, getIntExtra, etc (you should use the one that fits the extra type you sent)